# SPARK IN CLOUDERA

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera

I am new to HADOOP and SPARK ,
We have install cloudera VM ,we want to configure spark and scala,I have checked the below link for spark config ,but I am unable to complete it,
Can any one help me to config properly . 
http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_spark_configure.html
I have changed only host name what else I need to change .Please inform me.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at an old version of documentation.  Here is the latest version: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_spark_configure.html

As far as your Spark install, when you say that you installed the Cloudera VM, can you provide more detail? Do you mean the Quickstart VM they have for tutorials? https://www.cloudera.com/developers/get-started-with-hadoop-tutorial.html